# Does the brand name matter for a SSL EV certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Do end users really care if a SSL EV certificate is from VeriSign, Thwate, DigiCert, or etc.? A certificate from VeriSign can cost up to 3x the cost from DigiCert for the same basic features. VeriSign is probably the most recognizable brand name though.

I've had many discussions with people about this topic, but I've never seen any real data (from studies, surveys, etc.) to support the idea that end users will feel more secure using your site when they see the VeriSign seal vs. the DigiCert seal.

Does anyone have any real data to back up this idea?

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason Verisign can charge more is that as one of the very first CAs they are recognised by more legacy and obscure browsers.

Comment: But what percentage of users are on legacy or obscure browsers.  By covering IE 6,7, FF 2,3 Safari and Opera 8+, you probably cover about 99.99% of people who will ever visit your site.

Comment: Maybe its a bad attitude, but almost 99% of our users are IE7,IE6,FF,Safari,and Opera. If you're on IE5 or lower or something else, I don't care about you. Of course I still keep an eye on accessibility.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not saying it's a *good* reason these days, but the reputation sticks.

Comment: It's a significant oversimplification to say that brands don't matter and Verisign only commands a premium because of their longevity. That may account for *part* of the premium.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen much data on this either. The products are functionally the same. It seems hard to justify spending that much more on on a VeriSign certificate unless you are absolutely sure it will get you more money in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your customer.  If you are just serving to the general public, it's not going to make a big deal, because a lot of people don't even care as long as they see that little lock.  If you are dealing with a more technical system, possibly a web service where other developers are accessing sensitive data, you might run into some more "religious" people who insist that one is better than the other.

Comment: I tend to agree with you in that to the general public it's not a big deal. However my colleagues disagree and think that people will care about brand name. So the argument then comes down to two different subjective opinions. How can we make an objective decision?

Comment: I think that "religious" types will not like VeriSign. And serious people will not like COMODO.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're considering the fact that the EV provider might be giving you a logo to put on your site - during checkout or whatever. I'm not worried at all about people clicking on the lock and seeing a company they don't trust.

Companies with the word 'trust' are going to look better than those without - as far as an SSL validation seal logo goes.

Some SSL seals i've seen just look plain awful. Check out the logo in advance before you buy.

Answer (score 0):

I have been handling digital marketing activities for our company reselling SSL certificate since last couple of years and based on my experience, i found that; SSL certificate by verisign(symantec) and geotrust are most popular and trusted brand.

I also found that, SSL certificate can improve your customer confidence that can directly affect your conversion rate. But the main question is; how much? if you think your product and business is big and your target audience is technical enough to understand the SSL security, you should invest more/less in SSL certificate.